# AutoMapper testing and dependency injection for resolvers

Tags: ioc-container, automapper

Im writing a test for an automapper map. One of the destination members in the map requires a value resolver, and that value resolver has service dependencies which are injected. I want to use the real implementation for the resolver (since thats part of the map im testing) but Id like to use mocks for the dependencies the resolver has.

Ofcourse I want to try to avoid using an ioc container for in my tests, but how do I easily resolve my value resolver's dependencies without one?

This is my rather simplified example, in the real case there are several resolvers with sometimes many dependencies, and I really dont like to basically implement my own dependency resolver in my tests. Should I use a lightweight ioc container?

```
        [TestFixture]
        public class MapperTest
        {
            private IMyService myService;

            [SetUp]
            public void Setup()
            {
                Mapper.Initialize(config =>
                                    {
                                    config.ConstructServicesUsing(Resolve);
                                    config.AddProfile<MyProfile>();
                                    });
            }

            public T Resolve<T>()
            {
                return (T) Resolve(typeof (T));
            }

            public object Resolve(Type type)
            {
                if (type == typeof(MyValueResolver))
                    return new MyValueResolver(Resolve<IMyService>());
                if (type == typeof(IMyService))
                    return myService;
                Assert.Fail("Can not resolve type " + type.AssemblyQualifiedName);
                return null;
            }

            [Test]
            public void ShouldConfigureCorrectly()
            {
                Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
            }

            [Test]
            public void ShouldMapStuff()
            {
                var source = new Source() {...};
                var child = new Child();
                myService = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IMyService>();

                myService .Stub(x => x.DoServiceStuff(source)).Return(child);

                var result = Mapper.Map<ISource, Destination>(source);

                result.Should().Not.Be.Null();
                result.Child.Should().Be.SameInstanceAs(child);
            }

        }


        public class MyProfile : Profile
        {

            protected override void Configure()
            {
                base.Configure();

                CreateMap<ISource, Destination>()
                    .ForMember(m => m.Child, c => c.ResolveUsing<MyResolver>());

            }

       }

       public class MyResolver: ValueResolver<ISource, Destination>
        {
            private readonly IMyService _myService;

            public MyResolver(IMyService myService)
            {
                _myService = myService;
            }

            protected override Child ResolveCore(ISource source)
            {
                             return _myService.DoServiceStuff(source);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution, but basically its what iv done already:

http://groups.google.com/group/automapper-users/browse_thread/thread/aea8bbe32b1f590a/f3185d30322d8109

The suggestion is to use a service locator which are set up differently depending on test or real implementation.